# Compliant way to parse a 64 bit integer using sscanf with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, c89, ansi-c

I compiled the following **`c`** program with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define  BUFFER 21
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint64_t num = 0x1337C0DE;
  char str[BUFFER]; /* Safely Holds UINT64_MAX */
  if(argc > 1)
    sscanf(argv[1],"%llu",&num);
  sprintf(str,"%llu",num);
  return 0;
}
```

And I receive the following warnings:

```
test.c:8:5: warning: ISO C90 does not support the ‘ll’ gnu_scanf length modifier
test.c:9:3: warning: ISO C90 does not support the ‘ll’ gnu_printf length modifier
```

What is the correct, `C90` standards compliant, way to a parse/print 64 bit integer from/to a string,
which doesn't generate these warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is none. The largest integer type in C 90 is `long`, which is only guaranteed to be at least 32 bits. Since there's no integer type guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, there's also no way to read a 64-bit integer in C90 either. Of course, `long` *could* be 64 bits (it has been in at least one implementation, but there's no certainty that it is.

Comment: Then, from my understanding, I should make the code at minimum `C99` standards compliant if I need to use 64 bit values?

Comment: @awashburn: Yes -- C99 was the first to provide a type that was guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: @awashburn and with C99 you get the correct macros to handle `uint64_t` in `printf` and `scanf` for free. Since you tag your question with gcc, there is really no point in not using C99 these days, unless you have badly written hereditary code.

Answer (score -1):

you can use macros `SCNu64` and `PRIu64` in `<inttypes.h>`,
for your example, they can be

```
sscanf(argv[1],"%" SCNu64,&num);
```

```
sprintf(str,"%" PRIu64,num);
```

Comment: `inttypes.h` is a new header in C99 so it won't help in C89